# Leaflet : How can I display only one instance of Map?

Tags: angular, leaflet, maps, zooming, react-leaflet

On zoom out( zoom level =0), leaflet shows 4 instance of map, How can I show only 1 instance of map when zoom out at 0 level and fit to bounds of screen.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried noWrap: false

Comment: No, I dint tried this option, where do I need to define no Wrap property?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the noWrap option when including the tile layer. Like this:

```
L.tileLayer(urlTemplate, {
  noWrap: true,              //this is the crucial line!
  bounds: [
    [-90, -180],
    [90, 180]
  ]
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, it works for me.
One question : how can I make sure map does not show this grey blank space ?

Comment: You probably should try `map.fitWorld();` or `map.fitBounds();` for another extent than the whole world.

Comment: Did you add some bounds to `fitBounds()`? Like this `map.fitBound([[-90, -180],[90, 180]])` or any other value that makes sense for your map. Also this assumes your map object is called 'map'. Some people call it 'mymap' or something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Add noWrap in configuration options

```
 {
      noWrap: true,             
      bounds: [
        [-x, -y],
        [x, y]
      ]
    }
```